# Escaping quotes in velocity template

Tags: java, velocity, quotes

I have a java method, that takes a few strings. This method needs to be called from a Velocity Template. However, the strings are too complex, with lots of single quotes, double quotes and commas as well. As a result merge is failing. Is there a way to escape quotes in Velocity?

Answer (score 43, accepted):

It depends on which version of Velocity you're using. Velocity 1.7 has clear rules for escaping quotes: just double the same type of quotes used to wrap the string:

```
$object.callMethod('Let''s have fun with "quotes"',
  "Let's have fun with ""quotes""")
```

Prior to that, there were some fuzzy rules with backslash escapes that didn't always work as expected.

Comment: This is unfortunately not documented in the [Velocity User Guide](http://velocity.apache.org/engine/releases/velocity-1.7/user-guide.html).

Comment: Life saver, multumesc!

Answer (score 2):

See the Velocity Escape Tool:

https://velocity.apache.org/tools/2.0/apidocs/org/apache/velocity/tools/generic/EscapeTool.html