# How to print string in Apache velocity

Tags: velocity

i want to print a string as a valuei tried following macro[2] and "set"[1] option too but still no luck;

[1]

```
#set( $faultVar = "#if($faultSeq)$faultSeq#{else}fault#end")

<resource faultVar="$faultVar">
```

This prints for else case like  `<resource faultVar="">` , but I expect  `<resource faultVar="fault">`

[2]

```
#macro ( print_string_if_exist $field $default)
        #if($field && "$field" !="")
            $field
        #else
            $default
        #end
#end
```

This prints for edefault case like  `<resource faultVar="">` , but I expect  `<resource faultVar="fault">`

How can i make my velocity teplate to print like;
`<resource faultVar="fault">`   ?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Escaping quotes in velocity template](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19579748/escaping-quotes-in-velocity-template)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I corrected my macro to look like this:

```
#macro ( print_string_if_exist $field $default)
    #if($field && "$field" !="")
       "$field"
    #else
        "$default"
    #end
#end
```