# Escaping Double Quotes in Velocity

Tags: velocity

I have a string which i am getting

```
#set($locator=$dataElement.getLocator().get(0))
#set($selector = $locator.getSelector())
```

$selector is string type and it contains double quotes as well

when i am calling

```
executor.click(new Params("$selector",BY.$By));
```

selector have double quotes, which needs to be replaced with single quotes.

i tried with replacing but it is giving error

i referred question

[Escaping quotes in velocity template](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19579748/escaping-quotes-in-velocity-template?answertab=active#tab-top)

But this also don't solved my purpose

**example**

$selector can be something like

```
 a[@href="somelink"]
```

and i want that to changed to

```
a[@href='someLink']
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For velocity

```
$selector.replaceAll('"',"'")
```

replaces " with '

so something like:

```
executor.click(new Params("$selector.replaceAll('"',"'")",BY.$By));
```

this works fine